# Mount vue component - Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to do this in Vue 3

```
new ComponentName({ 
  propsData: {
    title: 'hello world',
  }
}).$mount();
```

But I'm getting this error: `VueComponents_component_name__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default is not a constructor`

Currently, we are using the above approach to append VUE components in our legacy app via `append`

I would like to do the same on VUE 3 but I haven't found the way to do it

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can't mount a component, you need to mount the app and add the component to the app. see [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-registration.html#component-names)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the solution to my answer, mounting a vue component in vue 3 (Outside vue projects) is different than vue 2, this is the approach :

```
// mount.js

import { createVNode, render } from 'vue'

export const mount = (component, { props, children, element, app } = {}) => {
    let el = element

    let vNode = createVNode(component, props, children)
    if (app && app._context) vNode.appContext = app._context
    if (el) render(vNode, el)
    else if (typeof document !== 'undefined' ) render(vNode, el = document.createElement('div'))

    const destroy = () => {
        if (el) render(null, el)
        el = null
        vNode = null
    }

    return { vNode, destroy, el }
}
```

- el: DOM element to be appended
- vNode: Vue instance
- destroy: Destroy the component

This is the way to mount vue 3 components to be appended directly to the DOM, and can be used as below:

```
// main.js

import { mount } from 'mount.js'

const { el, vNode, destroy } = mount(MyVueComponents,
      {
          props: {
            fields,
            labels,
            options
           },
           app: MyVueApp
      },
)

$element.html(el);
```

Hope it Helps, regards!

Comment: Hello ! Is it possible to have more context ? I was using this part of code with Vue 2 in a method of mixin, that I load in my app. I have the same error, but I don't understand some things..

How do you import the mount function ? And from where you get the instance app to pass in arguments of mount ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: how does this $element appear?

Comment: The instance app MyVueApp can be imported from App.Vue that is usually found at the root of the project. The app is just a Vue component that is defined using `defineComponent` and exported. So bottom line you can do `import MyVueApp from '../../App'`

Answer (score 1):

Just for future visitors to save some time, I was searching for the same answer and found a plug-in that does exactly what Luis explained  en his answer at https://github.com/pearofducks/mount-vue-component

Makes it a little simpler to implement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to create a new vue3 app and mount to a DOM directly,

```
    const appDef = {
        data() {
            return {title: 'hello world'};
        },
        template: '<div>title is: {{title}}</div>',
    }

    var el = document.createElement('div');//create container for the app

    const app = Vue.createApp(appDef);
    app.mount(el);//mount to DOM
    
    //el: DOM element to be appended
    console.log(el.innerHTML);//title is: hello world
```